# To need a way of thinking about Ji_Chen's nice result $(a- c)^{2}+ (b- d)^{2}\geq\frac{7}{9}ab- \frac{7}{20}(c^{2}+ 4d^{2})$

Tags: problem-solving, alternative-proof, irreducible-polynomials, discriminant, sum-of-squares-method

*given* four real numbers $a, b, c, d$

> Ji Chen gave a nice result [on.AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h21336p2268961)
> $$\left ( a- c \right )^{2}+ \left ( b- d \right )^{2}\geq\frac{7}{9}ab- \frac{7}{20}\left ( c^{2}+ 4d^{2} \right )$$

The original problem consists a condition $ab= c^{2}+ 4d^{2}= 4$ and hides the rightside of the earlier inequality, I wondered that how he could find this.. of course I searched in AoPS because of him *but* I also found another interesting work, which made me sense.

> He (AoPS/@ye109) claimed that
> $$\left ( a- c \right )^{2}+ \left ( b- d \right )^{2}\geq\frac{2\left ( k^{4}- 4 \right )}{3k^{2}}ab+ \frac{k^{4}- 4}{k^{4}- 16}\left ( c^{2}+ 4d^{2} \right )$$
> with the best $k\cong 1.672955253$ is a real root of $k^{12}- 28k^{8}- 36k^{6}- 128k^{4}+ 1024$

That guy is very good at making second solution, we just need explain his solution from Ji Chen's 1st one, if Ji Chen *used* discriminant to find $7/9, -7/20$ then *how* could he use discriminant to find $\frac{2\left ( k^{4}- 4 \right )}{3k^{2}}, \frac{k^{4}- 4}{k^{4}- 16},$ maybe there could exist discriminant for polynomials not only for constants. What's your idea ? Who can give me a way of thinking ? Thanks a real lot !

Comment: great, ye109, +1)

Comment: @tthnew, I tried to make everything clearer than before, I hope this topic received more than upvotes.

Comment: Mr. River Li is better! You may ask him for help.

Comment: Mr. @RiverLi doesn't use trick.

Comment: @haidangel Yes, I know little about trick. I use computer and BW usually.

Comment: @haidangel We hope to find some $q$ such that the following holds for all reals $a, b, c, d$
$$(a - c)^2 + (b - d)^2 \ge \frac{8}{5}\left(q \cdot \frac{ab}{4} + (1-q)\cdot \frac{c^2 + 4d^2}{4}\right).$$ Then, use discriminant, or use sufficient conditions for positive definite matrix, we can get the sufficient conditions for $q$. Then e.g. $q=2$, works.

Comment: I'm so obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left ( a- c \right )^{2}+ \left ( b- d \right )^{2}\geq Uab-V \left ( c^{2}+ 4d^{2} \right )$$
(for all reals $a,b,c,d$)

precisely when $$  V \geq 0$$  and
$$ |U| \leq \frac{4V}{\sqrt{(1+V)(1+4V)}}  $$

In turn, the largest $U$ is rational when
$$  V = \frac{m^2 - n^2}{4n^2 - m^2} \geq 0$$
where we get
$$ |U| \leq 4\frac{|m^2-n^2|}{3mn} $$

In particular, when we take $n=3,m=4$ we get $V= 7/20$ and the largest $|U|$ that still gives positive semidefinite is $7/9$

The positive semidefinite matrix with extremal $|U|$

using $2n > m > n,$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&\frac{2m^2-2n^2}{3mn}&-1&0\\
\frac{2m^2-2n^2}{3mn}&1&0&-1\\
-1&0&\frac{3n^2}{4n^2-m^2}&0\\
0&-1&0&\frac{3m^2}{4n^2-m^2}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

it's about a symmetric matrix, the Hessian of your quadratic form, being positive semidefinite.

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 7 }{ 18 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 324 }{ 275 }  &  \frac{ 126 }{ 275 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 18 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 12 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
180 &  - 70 &  - 180 & 0 \\ 
 - 70 & 180 & 0 &  - 180 \\ 
 - 180 & 0 & 243 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 180 & 0 & 432 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 18 }  &  \frac{ 324 }{ 275 }  &  \frac{ 18 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 126 }{ 275 }  &  \frac{ 12 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
180 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1375 }{ 9 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1701 }{ 55 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 7 }{ 18 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 126 }{ 275 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 324 }{ 275 }  &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
180 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1375 }{ 9 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1701 }{ 55 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 18 }  &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 126 }{ 275 }  &  -  \frac{ 324 }{ 275 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
180 &  - 70 &  - 180 & 0 \\ 
 - 70 & 180 & 0 &  - 180 \\ 
 - 180 & 0 & 243 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 180 & 0 & 432 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia

Comment: Oh my, thank U.